# What objective do gradient descent and steepest descent maximize when solving linear systems with infinite solutions?

Tags: optimization, systems-of-equations, linear-programming, numerical-linear-algebra, gradient-descent

When we use various local heuristic optimization methods for the solving of linear systems $Ax=b$ (e.g. gradient descent, steepest descent ($L_1$ norm), conjugate gradients), we implicitly are trying to minimize $||Ax-b||^2$ (or maybe some other norm).

When the system has infinite solutions, each of these methods $k$ may arrive at a different satisfying solution $x_k^*$, where $Ax_k^*=b$ $\forall$ $k$.

Presumably, each of these solutions $x_k^*$ maximize a different objective function, with a constraint being $Ax=b$ for each.  In other words, $x_k^*$ is the unique solution to

$$ 
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{maximize}  & \Omega_k \\
\text{subject to} & Ax=b .
\end{array}
$$

My question is: for each method $k$ (particularly I'm interested in steepest descent with the $L_1$ norm), **how do we determine what objective $\Omega_k$ is maximizing**?  Is there any theory here?

**Update:** Agree maximized objective can be a function not just of method $k$ but initial point $x_0$, so what I'm looking for maybe more like how to determine $\Omega_{k,x_0}$.

**Update 2:** Since the space is convex, can we say that:

Gradient Descent: $\Omega_{k,x_0} = ||x-x_0||_2$

Steepest Descent: $\Omega_{k,x_0} = ||x-x_0||_1$

(and that we are minimizing not maximizing)

?

Comment: Usually, they minimize the residual on the $k$-th Krylov space

Comment: A lot of these methods (specifically iterative methods) will have different solutions depending on the initial point, so it is not entirely accurate to say "each method has a solution $x^*_k$." Even among different solutions for a given method (e.g., gradient descent with different initializations), I don't think it is the case that each solution is an optima of some objective within the space of solutions $Ax=b$.

Comment: Adding to @angryavian's point, some methods (e.g. Best approximation or Haugazeau-type algorithms) actually compute the orthogonal projection of the initial iterate onto the solution space $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^N\, |\, Ax=b\}$, so they are minimizing $\|x-x_0\|$ subject to $Ax=b$.

Comment: Note that gradient descent can be made to converge to *any* minimizer of $\| Ax - b \|^2$ just by picking an appropriate starting point. Proof: Suppose that $x^*$ is a minimizer of $\| Ax - b \|^2$. Initialize gradient descent to start at $x^*$. Then gradient descent converges immediately to $x^*$.

Comment: @littleO, to my note, can we say that, since the region is convex, gradient descent converges to the closest minimizer to the starting point $x_0$ by Euclidean distance? (And same with steepest descent, but by Manhattan distance)?

Comment: The minimizer that gradient descent converges to depends also on what step size you use, or which line search procedure you use (if you use a line search procedure). So you would have to take that into account. I'm not aware of any results along the lines of what you're suggesting.

Comment: @littleO with an infinitesimally small step size would this be true?

Comment: @dashnick You can imagine an example where the solution of $Ax=b$ closest to the initial point $x_0$ is not in the direction you would first take in gradient descent. The step size might be chosen so that the algorithm finds a solution in one step, but since it is in a different direction that solution isn't the closest solution to $x_0$.

Comment: @angryavian but with sufficiently small step size does this hold?

Comment: @dashnick Again, not necessarily. The path to the nearest solution might be flat at first, and then drop drastically near the solution, but a greedy algorithm will ignore this path because of the flatness in the beginning. The greedy algorithm will go down the path that is steepest first, but it is possible that this path ends up in a flat region later that takes a long time before finally reaching a solution.

Comment: @angryavian thanks.   can you imagine a condition we could add that would make this hold in the small-step-size case?

Comment: @dashnick I think you can use a variant of Halpern's algorithm to do what you're asking. You can interpret the vanishing viscosity parameter as a step size. Note this only works for the Euclidean distance for your case (in general this is true for a Hilbertian norm, but the Manhattan distance/1-norm is not Hilbertian). Since your objective function is convex, the Baillon-Haddad theorem guarantees your gradient is firmly nonexpansive, so if you phrase gradient descent in a Halpern framework, that argument might work. For reference, check out Chapter 30 of Bauschke & Combettes' book, volume 2.

Comment: @dashnick -- by that, I mean the Halpern algorithm will converge to the projection of a point onto the solution set, and it uses a parameter that goes to zero which can sort-of be interpreted as a decreasing step size